# How to share android DB from one device to another

Tags: android, database

I am working on POS application. The app installed 4 different devices. When device 1 takes an order need to update device 2, 3 and 4. If the order takes from device 3 I need to update 1, 2 and 4. I there any way to share the data b/w the devices over the network.

Comment: web services ??

Comment: Broadcasting like blockchain :-)

Comment: Why you are not trying to store data on server using Web API or Web Services?

Comment: @anantjaiswal i need to work the app if there is any problem with internet

Comment: Could [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)  help?